# junit object initialization for large objects

Tags: junit

In our JUnit tests, we have to initialize objects that are massive. We have objects within objects within objects. For example:

```java
class A {
    List<B> bList;
}

class B {
    List<C> cList;
}

class C {
    List<D> dList;
}
```

As you can already tell, our `setUp()` methods can become quite unwieldy.  Additionally, since we use these objects all over the place, we've created a util class that will create an `A` object along with all of its members. so if we need it in a JUnit, we'll just call `MyUtil.createA()`.

Is there a better/easier way to do this? Perhaps even another technology that makes this task a lot less tedious?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I have run into this a lot and the way you are going about it is the solution. However, I have found a nice patter (using `ParameterSupplier`) that allows for detailed control of each level. Imagine the following tests:

```
@Theory
public void testSetup1(@DefaultAList @DefaultBList @DefaultCList A a){...}


@Theory
public void testSetup2(@DefaultAList @DefaultBList @SomeOtherCList(config="blah") A a){...}
```

By using the pattern I have, you can easily control the entire structure of your instance. The basic idea is that you have a `TestSupplier` class that have static method for creating instances of the class. In the `TestSupplier` to provide annotations that can be used by `ParameterSupplier` and therefore `Theories`. These then allow you to specify how to create a complex multi-level object.

Here is an example test: [ExampleTest.java](https://github.com/dancerjohn/TestExamples/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jjbutler/parametersupplierexample/ExampleTest.java)

Here is the entire example project showing how to set up the `TestSuppliers`: [TestExamples](https://github.com/dancerjohn/TestExamples)

Here is the example tests from **ExampleTest**:

```
@Theory
public void test1(
        @DefaultTopBean @SingleMiddleBean @SingleValidBottomBean 
            TopBean topBean) {...}

@Theory
public void test2(
        @DefaultTopBean @SingleMiddleBean @InvalidBottomBean 
            TopBean topBean) {...}

@Theory
public void test3(
         @DefaultTopBean 
         @MiddleBeansWithState(states = { State.State1, State.State3 }) 
         @MultipleValidBottomBean(count = 2) 
               TopBean topBean) {...}
```